# Perl Section in Apache config don't work

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, perl, mod-perl

I have installed mod_perl on my server via yum to make use of Perl sections in the Apache config. I'm running Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6. I installed the necessary Perl modules (DB2 driver mainly) via cpan.

This is the script:

```
<Perl>
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# @File ApacheDomainHandler.pl
# @Author Martin
# @Created 05.01.2015 16:53:45
#

use strict;
use warnings;

# use module
use XML::Simple;
use DBI;
use Apache2::ServerUtil();
use Apache::PerlSections();

my $apache = Apache2::ServerUtil->server;
my $database = 'dbi:DB2:XXXXXX'; 
my $user = 'XXXXXXXX'; 
my $password = 'XXXXXX';
my $schema = 'XXXX'; 
my $blogapiurl = 'http://localhost'; 

my $dbh = DBI->connect($database, $user, $password)
        or die "Can't connect to $database: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
                qq{ SELECT "businessXML" from $schema."Organisations" }
        )
        or die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";

my $rc = $sth->execute
        or die "Can't execute statement: $DBI::errstr";

my $businessXML;
while (($businessXML) = $sth->fetchrow()) {
        my $xml = XMLin($businessXML);
        if($xml && $xml->{website}){

                my $url = URI->new($xml->{website});
                if($url->host){

                        my $host = $url->host;
                        my $orgId = $xml->{id};

                        my $vhost = qq{
                                <VirtualHost *:80>

                                        ServerName $host

                                        ProxyPreserveHost Off
                                        ProxyPass /assets $blogapiurl/assets
                                        ProxyPassReverse /assets $blogapiurl/assets

                                        ProxyPass / $blogapiurl/user/$orgId/
                                        ProxyPassReverse / $blogapiurl/user/$orgId/

                                </VirtualHost>
                        };

                        //$apache->add_config($vhost);
                        $apache->add_config([$vhost]);
                }

        }
}

# check for problems which may have terminated the fetch early
warn $DBI::errstr if $DBI::err;

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
print STDERR Apache::PerlSections->dump( );
</Perl>
```

I think the server is not using the script at all. Dump doesn't give me anything in the error_log. How can I check if Apache is really using my script?

Comment: The `pre`of stackoverflow obviously "eats" the `<Perl></Perl>` tags in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: format as code by pre-pending 4 spaces to every line, does it now looks as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... you can't add multiple lines with `add_config()`. Instead, first create an array containing each line and then add this array to the config:

```
my $vhost = [
    "<VirtualHost *:80>",

        "ServerName $host",

        "ProxyPreserveHost Off",
        "ProxyPass /assets $blogapiurl/assets",
        "ProxyPassReverse /assets $blogapiurl/assets",

        "ProxyPass / $blogapiurl/user/$orgId/",
        "ProxyPassReverse / $blogapiurl/user/$orgId/",

    "</VirtualHost>"
];

$apache->add_config($vhost);
```